# vue + chosen-js: can not import css of chosen-js with chosen-sprite.png

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, jquery-chosen

I am using npm and Vue and Webpack. I want to use Chosen library with jQuery, But I can not import `chosen-js/chosen.css` because I got a error. How to import css file of Chosen?

Code:

```
<script>
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
import chosen from 'chosen-js';
import 'chosen-js/chosen.css';

export default {
    mounted: function() {
        $('.select').chosen({
            search_contains: true,
        });
    },
};
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <select class="select">
            <option selected>aaa</option>
            <option>bbb</option>
            <option>ccc</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/chosen-js/chosen-sprite.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

Comment: You might need an image loader for webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

Comment: oh thanks. I add file-loader to webpack.config.js, that is work fine.

Comment: I added an answer for future readers to see. glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an image loader so WebPack knows how to handle png files. This will also give you the option of compressing image files during the bundling process.  Here's a link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

Answer (score 0):

Install and add file-loader to webpack.config.js, That is works fine.